# Not able to run Protractor tests (5.0.0) on IE11

Tags: protractor

Protractor : 5.0.0, IE11, IEDriverServer_Win32_3.0.0.exe

conf file:

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'internet explorer',
}
localSeleniumStandaloneOpts: {
    jvmArgs: ["-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=.\\node_modules\\protractor\\node_modules\\webdriver-manager\\selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe"]
}
```

IE browsers opens up but doesn't do anything. Following is the error

```
[11:12:22] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[11:12:22] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[11:12:23] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.56.1:53122/wd/hub
Started
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
F[11:12:26] E/launcher - Unable to get browser (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'RLAPTOP', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.forceShellWindowsApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:36498/, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: e830e362-bb50-41bb-8b2d-cd4bd35f6d4d
[11:12:26] E/launcher - NoSuchWindowError: Unable to get browser (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'RLAPTOP', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.forceShellWindowsApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:36498/, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: e830e362-bb50-41bb-8b2d-cd4bd35f6d4d
    at WebDriverError (C:\QA\testingmaster\tests\protractor_tests\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27:5)
    at NoSuchWindowError (C:\QA\testingmaster\tests\protractor_tests\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:192:5)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\QA\testingmaster\tests\protractor_tests\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:505:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\QA\testingmaster\tests\protractor_tests\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (C:\QA\testingmaster\tests\protractor_tests\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:440:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.getCurrentUrl()
    at WebDriver.schedule (C:\QA\testingmaster\tests\protractor_tests\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:816:17)
    at WebDriver.getCurrentUrl (C:\QA\testingmaster\tests\protractor_tests\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1002:17)
    at ScreenshotReporter.specDone (C:\QA\testingmaster\tests\protractor_tests\e2e\jasmine_reporters\screenshot_reporter.js:12:22)
    at dispatch (C:\QA\testingmaster\tests\protractor_tests\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1966:28)
    at ReportDispatcher.specDone (C:\QA\testingmaster\tests\protractor_tests\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1949:11)
    at Spec.specResultCallback [as resultCallback] (C:\QA\testingmaster\tests\protractor_tests\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:903:18)
    at complete (C:\QA\testingmaster\tests\protractor_tests\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:368:12)
    at QueueRunner.clearStack (C:\QA\testingmaster\tests\protractor_tests\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:660:9)
    at QueueRunner.run (C:\QA\testingmaster\tests\protractor_tests\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1881:12)
    at C:\QA\testingmaster\tests\protractor_tests\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1898:16
[11:12:26] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

Any suggestions? Do i need to start selenium server as well manually ?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @bmsdave no, sorry!